# How to set All the JWT token in header

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
 const getBlog = async () =>{
      const url = `${host}/blog/fetch-user-blog`;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjM3NzkzYTE2ODlkNzc3Y2E0NjIyMWEzIn0sImlhdCI6MTY2ODg0MTU4OX0.gCCy5LGk48N3k5wTPW5SOxfkfg6AKhnluCeCGwJbgrI"
        }
      });
      const data = await response.json()
      setBlogs(data);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to set all the JWT token in the header as im trying to get all the blogs, currently im using only one user auth token but i need to use all the users auth token

Comment: You cannot include more than one authentication token in a request. You cannot authenticate as two or more users at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you should use axios

set header to axios

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjM3NzkzYTE2ODlkNzc3Y2E0NjIyMWEzIn0sImlhdCI6MTY2ODg0MTU4OX0.gCCy5LGk48N3k5wTPW5SOxfkfg6AKhnluCeCGwJbgrI"
        }
```

then anywhere in your application
use `axios.[METHOD_NAME]` you dont need to define header there.